# Reading from config file in Spring Boot - TestNG

Tags: spring-boot, testng, config

I am using TestNG with Spring Boot for a rest assured testing project,
I have the baseurl and few endpoints in the application.properties file.

When I try to access the `@Value` I am not able to get the values.

```
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class GetRuleapi {

    private final static Logger apilogger = Logger.getLogger(Logger.class.getName());

    @Value("${baseUrl}")
    private String baseUrl;
```

The application.prope‌​rties is in `src\test\resourc‌​es\application.prope‌​rties`

Any example would greatly help.

Comment: Can you show some code what you have tried so far?

Comment: this is the tester class

Comment: @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")


public class GetRuleapi
{
    private final static Logger apilogger = Logger.getLogger(Logger.class.getName()); //setting up the logger

    @Value("${baseUrl}")
    private String baseUrl;

Comment: and the application.prop is in C:\Users\murali.velaga\IdeaProjects\Restapi\src\test\resources\application.properties

Comment: The test class should extend `org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests`

Answer (score 0):

OK, if this is the test class then it should look like this

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestNGWithSpringApplication.class)
public class ApplicationPropertiesExampleIT extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

    @Value("${baseUrl}")
    private String baseUrl;
```

***TestNGWithSpringApplication*** is something like this

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TestNGWithSpringApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestNGWithSpringApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

***application.properties*** should be placed in ***src/test/resources*** folder. The parameter in ***application.properties*** should be

```
baseUrl=http://www.lenar.io/get-parameters-from-application-properties-file/
```